# Image inside UILabel text

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need an idea how to put image to uilabel text. The text should look like this:

"Hello press 'image', then press 'image2', after that you press 'image3'" and so on. The text is dynamic, so adding everything to static locations is not an option..

I simply would like to have reference to image in my text. Something like ("Text %@, hello", image)

Comment: You might have to subclass a `UIView` to achieve that and then implement `drawRect` method of it. Think along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to do that in label ?

you can do it easily by UIView and UILabel and UIButton , the

**[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]** will help you where to add your views by calculating each text width, so you can add your views dynamically ,

you need to assign the image as background to the UIButton

you add the first label then calculate where the first to add the first button and so on

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is take a UIView and on that UIView add UILabel, UIImage as Subviews.

It would look something like this

**UILabel1** UIImage1 **UILabel2** UIImage2 **UILabel3** UIImage3

Now regarding your catch about using dynamic text - All you have to do is calculate the size of UIView at the runtime depending on the following sizes:

- UILabels using the NSString API

  ```
   sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
  ```
- UIImages - it must be static I believe

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the classes  NSAttributedString+HTML.h and  NSAttributedString+HTML.m and use html to insert and image in the label.